# Reading an pixel array to Bitmap returns black image

Tags: c#

I have an pixel array which i want to open as a Bitmap.

The method i use is the following: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1264492:

```
/// <summary>
/// function CopyDataToBitmap
/// Purpose: Given the pixel data return a bitmap of size [352,288],PixelFormat=24RGB 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="data">Byte array with pixel data</param>
public Bitmap CopyDataToBitmap(byte[] data)
{
  //Here create the Bitmap to the know height, width and format
  Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap( 352, 288, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);  

  //Create a BitmapData and Lock all pixels to be written 
  BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(
                       new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),   
                       ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);

  //Copy the data from the byte array into BitmapData.Scan0
  Marshal.Copy(data, 0, bmpData.Scan0, data.Length);


  //Unlock the pixels
  bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);


  //Return the bitmap 
  return bmp;
}
```

I dont know much about the array, other than the image was black/white. The problem might be in the line: PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb. How can I tell the format without trying them all ?

Array looks like this:

```
"0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,0,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"
```

I am saving the image to disk like this:

```
var img = CopyDataToBitmap(result.Pixels);
img.Save("img.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: If you have only the array without knowing the data format it is holding, then it's not possible to do this in a generic way. You need to know the pixel format and the width/height of the image.

Comment: what if I dont know the width/height of the image, will it still be possible just by trying different formats until I hit the right one?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong. How do you know it's black? Save it to disk or something else? Problem could be in that code.

Comment: Wrong format or dimensions aside, I'd expect to see something

Comment: Save as png. The image is predominantly black. There are a few pixels not black. You want a lossless format just incase those pixels are getting lost in saving. I doubt it, but worth a shot

Comment: You could also try another smaller array that you know should work. Just a 4x4 pixel image.

Comment: Chaning to PNG got it to draw something, altough it's not pretty. I guess I need the width/height to get the real image as mentioned by @dymanoid. Thanks.

Comment: The white lines just seem to be stacked in the top of the image